# Depolyment on Virtual machine Scale sets using Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-vm-scale-set

I am facing issue while deploying updated code on vmscaleset using Azure DevOps Pipeline. Tried using updating Image each time when code updates in repo, but its taking much time. Kindly suggest  ways to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

By reference to this doc: [How Azure Pipelines manages the scale set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops), Azure Pipelines automatically scales the agent machines. Thus each time you run a build it will create new agents in Azure portal and your build will run when the new agents are idle and online, which takes much time.

You could choose to use [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) or [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install), which should take not much time.

Comment: I am asking about CD part not CI part. I want to Deploy code on vmss using azure pipelines. e.g.  AWS has codedeploy and it deploy code on AutoScaling group.

Comment: @user15589423 Can you specify which step(e.g. Initialize job
...) in the pipeline takes much time?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/azure/deploy-virtual-scale-set-java?view=azure-devops I follow this blog. It take much time for image build process.